# Flutter: create multiple events on calendar

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I use this package and it works ok for one calendar event:
https://pub.dev/packages/add_2_calendar

but how can I create multiple notifications at once? I don't mind to use a difference library for this

Comment: Why are you not able to do that with this package?

Comment: I think you need use another package with permissions to edit calendar from your app. this package create intent and send one object to calendar.

Comment: @Andrej how can you do it using this package? It doesn't have any instructions and I also created another question on its repo. Can you share some code here?

Comment: @HadiNorouzi do you know what package is that?

Comment: @Dani Have you solved this?

Comment: @Zookey yes but the solution is probably a bit different. Because I save everything on the database what I do is create them now on the database first and pick them for it

Comment: @Dani Thanks, but how do you insert multiple multiple events in the calendar?

Comment: what I mean is that this approach changes the whole logic and it goes beyond this question. My solution was doing that because I need to save it in the cloud first, but there is another approach to achieve this without doing something like that. You can ask directly on the repo for better support (not sure about that way, sorry)